# Traffic rerouting internally on LAN

Tags: routing, traffic

I have a LAN with 10 PC's and 2 routers. One of the routers creates a secure connection to a different location. We do not rights to administer this router.The other router is my internet gateway.

I have an application on my PC's that needs to connect to an IP address over the secured line. So basically, I would like to route that traffic to the secured router and over the secured line so the application is able to run. I would love to do it the easy way, locally on my PC's if it is possible. The PC's are running  XP Professional.

Comment: What kind of routers are there (both the one you manage and the one you don't)? Can you work with whoever does manage the other router to setup dynamic routing if both routers support it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a static route for the subnet in question, with the next hop pointing to the IP address of the second router.

You can do this by either adding a static route to each workstation, or preferably, by adding a static route to your main internet gateway router.

Microsoft provides documentation [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx?mfr=true) on how to add static routes to a Windows XP OS.